# Can the 'auto' keyword be used as a storage class specifier in C++11? 

Tags: c++, c++11, variable-declaration, storage-class-specifier

Can the `auto` keyword be used as a storage class specifier in C++11?

Is the following code legal in C++11?

```
int main() {
   auto int x;
}
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

No the code is ill-formed in C++11. `auto` in C++11 would be used to deduce the type of a variable from its initializer and it can't be used as a storage class specifier.

Correct Usage

```
int main()
{
   auto x = 12; // x is an int
   auto y = 12.3; // y is a double
}
```

Comment: So now it is C++ **11**, is it? I am getting confused. I hope this gets resolved by some official statement soon :)

Comment: @Space_C0wb0y : Yes most probably the official name would be C++11 :)

Comment: @Space_C0wb0y: not quite yet, when Sutter was asked the question he said he'd rather wait (no need to rush now) that the standard was really agreed upon before dubbing C++0x with its definitive millesime.

Comment: @Björn Pollex: Only if ISO makes it before January. If not, then not. Therefore, C++0x is still the more definite term (imho).

Answer (score 0):

```
auto int x;
```

is circular - you are literally declaring the type as an `int`.
given that you had this information - there is no reason to not simply use:

```
int x;
```

if you wanted to declare x the type of another variable in scope you can use `decltype`

```
using sometype = float;
sometype y;
decltype(y) x;
```